# Cryptographic secure PRNG-function for PHP?

Tags: php, prng

Is there a good open source script/library for php, that will produce cryptographic secure Pseudo-Random-Numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php, there is a warning that says, "This function does not generate cryptographically secure values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need a cryptographically secure value, consider using openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead".  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way is to simply read from /dev/urandom, but a plethora of examples can be found in this article (sorry for the non SO link):

http://timoh6.github.io/2013/11/05/Secure-random-numbers-for-PHP-developers.html

There is also a php library if this is what you are looking for:

https://gist.github.com/raveren/5555297